# How to set a local variable path into a python package?

Tags: python, path, package, local

I try to build a python package like that :

```
myPackage/
    myPackage.py
    conf/
        conf1.conf
        conf2.conf
```

When I build and install the package, all files are in the

> /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/myPackage

directory.

Fine.

BUT :
In myPackage.py file I need to set a local variable referring to my conf1.conf file
So I wrote :

```
path_conf1 = "conf/conf1.conf"
def myFunction(path_conf1):
    with open(path_conf1,"r") as f:
        # do something
```

But path_conf1 is unknown, because Python try to find it where I launch the script, not inside the myPackage itself.

I tried a lot of Google Search but I don't find that specific case.

How to deal with that issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell python the full file path.
One way of doing this is with the use of the os library.

```
import os
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

then you can add the end of you path on that. Something along the lines of

```
path_conf1 = path + path_conf1
```